# Set STS: see where the file is situated

Tags: eclipse

I would like to set my STS (or eclipse) in this way:

When I have opened some file, Or I am editing it, I would like to unroll the package explorer and mark the opened file, i do not know how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by selecting `Package explorer` of the `Show In` option at the editor's contextual menu.

By default, `Show In`'s shortcut is `Shift + Alt + W`, but you can also assign a shortcut to `Show In (Project Explorer)` at `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Keys`.

Comment: There's also the "Link with Editor" action from the Package Explorer toolbar for doing this automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. In contextual menu there is an oprtion link with editor. Thanks a lot.